# Values less than a threshold in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array, `sigma`. If any element of `sigma` is less than `threshold`, then the value of the specific element is equal to the `threshold`. The current and expected outputs are presented.

```
import numpy as np

sigma = np.array([[ 0.02109   ],
                  [ 0.01651925],
                  [ 0.02109   ],
                  [ 0.02109   ],
                  [ -0.009   ]])

threshold = 0.010545

for i in range(0, len(sigma)):
    if(sigma[i] <= threshold):
        sigma[i] == threshold

print([sigma])
```

The current output is

```
[array([[ 0.02109   ],
       [ 0.01651925],
       [ 0.02109   ],
       [ 0.02109   ],
       [-0.009     ]])]
```

The expected output is

```
[array([[0.02109   ],
       [0.01651925],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.010545  ]])]
```

Comment: `sigma[i]==threshold` --> `sigma[i]=threshold`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a good start you are doing a threshold. In fact, [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) has a good function to help you perform faster. That is *[np.clip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)*.

```
import numpy as np

sigma = np.array([[ 0.02109 ],
                  [ 0.01651925],
                  [ 0.02109   ],
                  [ 0.02109   ],
                  [ -0.009   ]])

threshold = 0.010545

np.clip(sigma, threshold, np.inf)
```

#### Output

```
array([[0.02109   ],
       [0.01651925],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.02109   ],
       [0.010545  ]])
```

*np.clip* is actually a function that limits your array within a boundary (with a minimum and maximum value). So, if you are performing array elementwise operation, you can use *np.clip* to make sure all the elements stay within the boundary.

Comment: So the gist is replacing the explicit loop with a built-in function? More idiomatic (and faster)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the code. You need to assign instead of comparing.

```
for i in range(0,len(sigma)):
    if(sigma[i]<=threshold):
        sigma[i]=threshold
```

Answer (score -2):

You just have a typo when assigning the value of the array:

```
for i in range(0, len(sigma)):
    if(sigma[i] <= threshold):
        sigma[i] == threshold
```

Comment: This is better posted as comment because it is not an answer to the question, but a suggestion for improvement

Comment: It's not an improvement its the issue with the code . it wasn't assigning the array element hence the wrong output . Also i couldn't add as a comment since i didnt have enough reputation ^^

Comment: The first version was better in that it showed the *correct* version. That isn't clear in the current revision.

Comment: This is a repeat of [Himanshuman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73010107/values-less-than-threshold-in-python/73010126#73010126) (which is also better explained (though not perfect)).

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.